# Signin with LinkedIn - How to validate token on server side

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I would like to allow users to login my web application using "Sign in with LinkedIn" *Javascript SDK*.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Once user logging in using LinkedIn i need to transfer (post) the Member ID to my application server and look for a user with that linkedIn memberid in my application database.

The problem is that i couldn't find an option to validate the member id i am getting from the javascript SDK in the server side in order to make sure the end user didn't manipulate it using Chrome Dev tools for example.

Without an option to validate the value on a server side, i assume that users will be able to change the member id value before it post to the server. Am i right?

i found few old threads but the solutions do not work

Answer (score 1):

If you want server side validation you should use the Oauth 2.0 approach.

Start by providing the initial link:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&response_type=code&state=[state]&scope=r_basicprofile">Li Auth</a>
```

And continue from there: 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2